# Canonicalization at homepage

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I have two pages which have the same content.

1. Homepage (www.example.com/)
2. Detail (www.example.com/detail)

On Homepage, there is shown exactly the same content as on the Detail page so there is a big problem with duplicate content.

I want to solve it using the tag

```
rel="canonical"
```

But what happens, if I put this tag to the Homepage directing the search engine to the Detail?
Will I completely loose the Homepage in the search results?

Note: The Homepage changes a few times a day, each time "copying" the content of another Detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines will consider home page as duplicate & discard.
Better way would be to re-direct detail page to Home page.

More details on [canonical tag, its impact & implementations](http://www.searchenabler.com/blog/canonical-tags-to-fix-duplicate-content/)

Comment: I don't think that it would be better to redirect the detail page to the homepage. This redirection would only last for one day, but search engines might cache it longer because they don't refresh the index daily for each site.